# How to capture the contents of a specific window with python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm doing a project which requires me to capture the contents of a particular window. Till now I was placing that window on a specific place on the screen and taking the screenshot of that part of the screen using mss library in python. Then I was using this image for further processing using opencv.

I was wondering if there is a better way to get contents of a window as a image.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
in the help documentation. Remember to include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described. Most notably, we need you to include the entire error message as well as enough data to get us to the problem point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture the screen output of a running program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552267/how-to-capture-the-screen-output-of-a-running-program)

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted. Thanks man...